# Can I have more Community Licenses?

Tags: partner-communities, userlicense

The project that I am working on, predicts to have more than 20 Partner Community Users, which is the maximum number of this kind of licenses, as you can see from the screenshot too.

How can I obtain other licenses? Should we buy the extra ones?

Thank you,
Endrit.

[image]

Comment: If its not developer edition you need to buy them.

Comment: Contact your Salesforce Account Executive to buy more, but bear in mind there are 2 licence types for Partners - normal Partner (named user licences) or Partner Community Login (max number of logins by partner users) available to make sure you get the most appropriate type for your company.